# Python Add Dataclass to Set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataclass defined like so:

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Speaker:
    id: int
    name: str
    statements: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id and self.name == other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.id, self.name))
```

and I have a list of names and statements which I want to combine.
Each item in the list is going to have an id which may be shared any number of times.
I want to append the statement part of each item in the list to the set of speakers.

This is what I have so far:

```py
test = [(1, 'john', 'foo'),(1, 'john', 'bar'),(2, 'jane', 'near'),(2, 'george', 'far')]

speakers = set()
for i in test:
    id, name, statement = i
    Speaker(id, name)
    
    # This line needs to change
    speakers.add(Speaker(id, name, [statement]))

print(speakers)
```

#### Current output

`{Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo']), Speaker(id=2, name= 'jane', statements=['near']), Speaker(id=2, name= 'george', statements=['far'])}`

#### What I want

`{Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo', 'bar']), Speaker(id=2, name= 'jane', statements=['near']), Speaker(id=2, name= 'george', statements=['far'])}`

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. The number fields are subject to change (I may add title, ect.), so converting to a dict probably won't work.

Edit:
Added an extra field called name to clarify the situation.

Comment: A set is not going to magically do that. You need to find the existing item in the set and merge the attributes yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `set`, I think it makes more sense to use a `dict` type in this case. This should be `O(1)` for lookup, and also this way we can avoid `next` to find an element by its `Speaker` hashed value. Example below.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Speaker:
    id: int
    name: str
    statements: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id and self.name == other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.id, self.name))


test = [(1, 'john', 'foo'), (1, 'john', 'bar'), (2, 'jane', 'near'), (2, 'george', 'far')]
speakers = {}

for id, name, statement in test:
    key = Speaker(id, name)
    speaker = speakers.setdefault(key, key)
    speaker.statements.append(statement)

print(speakers)
print()
pprint(list(speakers.values()))
```

Out:

```
{Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo', 'bar']): Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo', 'bar']), Speaker(id=2, name='jane', statements=['near']): Speaker(id=2, name='jane', statements=['near']), Speaker(id=2, name='george', statements=['far']): Speaker(id=2, name='george', statements=['far'])}

[Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo', 'bar']),
 Speaker(id=2, name='jane', statements=['near']),
 Speaker(id=2, name='george', statements=['far'])]
```

---

*Edit*: as the dataclass itself is hashable, here I think it makes sense to store the Speaker object itself (uniquely identified by `id`, `name`, any other fields that are defined in `__hash__`) as both the key and value. This is a little roundabout, so if you wanted you could also store the tuple of the values you want to hash - i.e. `(id, name)` - which should also work. In either case, this should still be more efficient since it uses `dict.setdefault` which is still `O(1)` time to best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, and actually a Dict was what I initially used. I switched to a data class though because there were more fields I wanted to match on (name, title, ect.) and I don't think a dict covers this case.

Comment: I added another field in the question to clarify this.

Comment: Right, so in your case you could just store the `Speaker` object as both the key and value, if you wanted to. You should be able to store it as a key directly, since you've implemented a `__hash__` for the dataclass.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is like so:

```
for i in test:
    id, statement = i
    new_speaker = Speaker(id, [statement])
    
    match = next((x for x in speakers if x == new_speaker), None)
    if match:
        match.statements.append(statement)
    else:
        speakers.add(new_speaker)
```

Not sure if there is a way which can do so in less time though, please comment if you think of any.

Answer (score 0):

If a set covers all use cases you have, but for merging  one or more fields, you can customize a set, so that all the set-changing calls do merge the attributes.

The easiest way to do that is to write a class derived from [`collections.abc.MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSet), which will both minimize the number of methods to be implemented, and ensure all changing calls go through your code (unlike, for example, subclassing Python's native `set`).

On a second thought: havign internally a set won't cut it  - a mapping is needed so that it is easy to retrieve an specific element in order to update it. This approach allows us to keep a set interface, though, and we may add "update" and "get" methods to it:

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class MergingSet(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self):
        # do not allow an initial content to avoid corner cases.
        # call .update  later to feed several instances at once
        self.data = dict()
        
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.data
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def discard(self, item):
        del self.data[item]
        self.data.discard(item)
        
    def add(self, item):
        if item in self:
            our_item = self.data[item]
            # hardcoded attribute merging:
            our_item.statements.extend(item.statements)
        else:
            self.data[item] = item
    
    def get(self, item):
        return self.data[item]  # returns the matching instance in the inner data, with the mutable fields
                                # modified.
                                
    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.add(item)

    def get(self, item, default=None):
        return self.data.get(item, default)    
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(set(self.data.keys()))
```

And running this with your example:

```
In [28]:     
    ...: test = [(1, 'john', 'foo'),(1, 'john', 'bar'),(2, 'jane', 'near'),(2, 'george', 'far')]
    ...: 

In [29]: speakers = MergingSet()

In [30]: for i in test:
    ...:     id, name, statement = i
    ...:     Speaker(id, name)
    ...:     
    ...:     # This line needs to change
    ...:     speakers.add(Speaker(id, name, [statement]))
    ...:     

In [31]: speakers
Out[31]: {Speaker(id=2, name='jane', statements=['near']), Speaker(id=1, name='john', statements=['foo', 'bar']), Speaker(id=2, name='george', statements=['far'])}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that using a Merging set is a good way to go about this while changing as few lines of code as possible. However I do think creating a custom mutable set is overkill when underlying it is a dictionary anyways.